# How to get legends to show up for a plot of an ODE with differing initial values?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, legending

I'm trying to get legends for different initial values for the solutions to an ode to show up. I currently have

```
g[t_] = Piecewise[{{2, t <= 3}, {0, t > 3}}];
ode = R*c*v'[t] + v[t] == g[t];
sol = DSolveValue[{ode, v[0] == z}, v, t];
Plot[Evaluate[sol[t] /. { z -> {0, 1, 2, 3}, R -> 2, c -> 0.3}], {t, 0, 6},  PlotLegends -> {"V = 0", "V = 1", "V = 2", "V = 3"}]
```

This shows four different lines, but all the same color and with only one legend. I have also tried doing Expressions, AllExpressions, and All and none of these worked either. I'm extremely new to Mathematica so you might have to spell out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[sol[t] /. {z -> z0, R -> 2, c -> 0.3}, {z0, {0, 1, 2, 
     3}}]], {t, 0, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"V = 0", "V = 1", "V = 2", "V = 3"}]`

Comment: To add to corey's comment, `z -> {0, 1, 2, 3}` is substituting in the full list, and `sol` isn't being applied to them separately. So, that's why he suggests using `Table`.

Answer (score 1):

```
g[t_] := Piecewise[{{2, t <= 3}, {0, t > 3}}]
ode = R*c*v'[t] + v[t] == g[t];
vF[z_] = DSolveValue[{ode, v[0] == z}, v, t] /. {R -> 2, c -> 0.3}

With[{zvals = Range[0, 3]},
  Plot[Evaluate @ Through[(vF /@ zvals)[t]], {t, 0, 6},
    PlotLegends -> (Row[{"V = ", #}] &) /@ zvals]]
```

[image: plot]

You could also write

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Through[(vF /@ #)[t]], {t, 0, 6},
  PlotLegends -> (Row[{"V = ", #}] &) /@ #] & @ Range[0, 3]
```

but that's getting a little too much like code golf and too obscure for me to be happy with it.